# Как получить значение тега

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Есть html, из которой я хочу получить информацию. Использую HtmlAgilityPack

```
<div class="more__2VudS more__30Xud">
      <div class="time__RkgeO time__4mUXN">
          01 Января 2018 в 17:03
      </div>
```

Хотел получить все что содержится в классе `time`, но результат не находит информацию. Есть подозрение что неправильно указал фильтр для `contains`

```
 var platform = ss[i].SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'time__')]").InnerText;
```

Comment: Я разумеется вас не агитирую отказаться от htmlagilitypack. Но рекомендую посмотреть на AngelSharp, там можно делать операции по DOM но при этом не каким-то своим синтаксисом а согласно стандартам w3c. Библиотека развита и постоянно развивается.

Comment: И на ней вот такой запрос бы вы могли использовать `div[class^="time"]`

Answer (score 1):

Всё же напишу как ответ, если вы решите использовать **AngleSharp**.

Его преимущество в том, что он полностью совместим и поддерживает современные браузерные стандарты. И в нём поиск нужного нода будет очень простым

```
// создаём парсер
var parser = new HtmlParser(); 
// наш докумен
var source = "<h1>Заголовок</h1> <div class=\"times__34232545\">some value</div>";
// парсим
var document = parser.Parse(source);
// достаём нужный элемент
var el = document.QuerySelector("div[class^=\"time\"]");
```

Это, разумеется просто пример кода, для вашей ситуации нужно будет сделать необходимую адаптацию

заметим что для поиска мы используем стандартный javascript / CSS синтаксис - https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Сайт парсера, библиотеки - https://anglesharp.github.io/
И сама документация - https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation